# State error propagation of ODE with uncertain parameters

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, error-propagation, kalman-filter, linearization

I have an idea on how to integrate uncertainty of the parameters of an ODE in the state error propagation. But I am unsure if my idea is correct. I have a non-linear ODE of the form:

$$ \frac{d}{dt} \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{x}, t, \boldsymbol{\beta}) = \sum_{i=1}^N \phi_i(\mathbf{x}, t) \cdot \beta_i$$

whereby $\phi_i(\mathbf{x}, t)$ are non-linear basis functions of $\mathbf{x}$.
When I use this ODE to propagate a state $\mathbf{x}_k = \mathbf{x}(t_k)$ with associated covariance matrix $\Sigma_{x_kx_k}$ I would like to also do error propagation in order to get the updated state $\mathbf{x}_{k+1}$ with associated $\Sigma_{x_{k+1}x_{k+1}}$.

The error propagation can be done using a linearization:
$$ \mathbf{T} = \frac{\partial \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{x}, t, \boldsymbol{\beta})}{\partial \mathbf{x}}|_{\mathbf{x}_k, t_k} $$

$$\boldsymbol{\Theta} = e^{\mathbf{T}\Delta t} $$
$$ \Sigma_{x_{k+1}x_{k+1}} = \boldsymbol{\Theta} \Sigma_{x_kx_k} \boldsymbol{\Theta}^T$$

Now to my problem: The coefficients of the ODE, $\boldsymbol{\beta}$, have their own covariance matrix $\Sigma_{\boldsymbol{\beta}\boldsymbol{\beta}}$ which I would also like to incorporate into the error propagation.

My idea for this is the following: Extend the linearized ODE to have $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ as part of the state vector:

$$ \frac{d}{dt}\begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{x} \\ \boldsymbol{\beta} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial \mathbf{F}}{\partial \mathbf{x}} && \frac{\partial \mathbf{F}}{\partial \boldsymbol{\beta}} \\ 0 && 0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{x} \\ \boldsymbol{\beta}\end{bmatrix} = \mathbf{T}^* \mathbf{x}^*$$

This extended system leaves the coefficient $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ unchanged and I can use it for the error propagation as before:

$$ \boldsymbol{\Theta}^* = e^{\mathbf{T}^*\Delta t} $$

Using the power series expansion:

$$ \boldsymbol{\Theta}^* = \mathbf{I} + \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial \mathbf{F}}{\partial \mathbf{x}} && \frac{\partial \mathbf{F}}{\partial \boldsymbol{\beta}} \\ 0 && 0\end{bmatrix} t +\begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial \mathbf{F}}{\partial \mathbf{x}} && \frac{\partial \mathbf{F}}{\partial \boldsymbol{\beta}} \\ 0 && 0\end{bmatrix}^2 \frac{t^2}{2!} + \dots + \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial \mathbf{F}}{\partial \mathbf{x}} && \frac{\partial \mathbf{F}}{\partial \boldsymbol{\beta}} \\ 0 && 0\end{bmatrix}^n \frac{t^n}{n!} + \dots $$
$$ = \mathbf{I} + \begin{bmatrix} \boldsymbol{\Theta}^*_1 && \boldsymbol{\Theta}^*_2 \\ 0 && 0\end{bmatrix} $$

$$ \boldsymbol{\Sigma}^* = \boldsymbol{\Theta}^* \begin{bmatrix} \Sigma_{x_{k}x_{k}} && 0 \\ 0 && \Sigma_{\beta\beta} \end{bmatrix} \boldsymbol{\Theta}^{*^T} $$

$$ = \begin{bmatrix} \Sigma_{x_{k+1}x_{k+1}} && \Sigma_{x_{k+1}\beta_{k+1}} \\ \Sigma_{\beta_{k+1}x_{k+1}} && \Sigma_{\beta_{k+1}\beta_{k+1}}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \Sigma_{x_{k}x_{k}} + 2\boldsymbol{\Theta}^*_1\Sigma_{x_{k}x_{k}} + \boldsymbol{\Theta}^*_1 \Sigma_{x_{k}x_{k}} \boldsymbol{\Theta}^*_1 + \boldsymbol{\Theta}^*_2 \Sigma_{\beta \beta} \boldsymbol{\Theta}^*_2 && \boldsymbol{\Theta}^*_2\Sigma_{\beta \beta} \\ \boldsymbol{\Theta}^*_2\Sigma_{\beta \beta} && \Sigma_{\beta\beta}\end{bmatrix} $$

Is this idea correct?

Comment: Nonlinear is very broad.  Are you acquainted with [differential inclusions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_inclusion)?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Unfortunately not. 
Does the type of nonlinear ODE determine the validity of my idea? I know that the linearization has limited accuracy, depending on how non-linear the function is and how large the uncertainties are. This idea arose from the update step of an extended kalmann filter in case you are familiar with it.

Comment: When you have polynomial  or rational functions, there is hope of using algebraic geometry.  When you have transcendental functions, it may be hopeless.

Comment: Yes, I am acquainted with Kalman filters.  When I think of Kalman filters and uncertainty, the name that comes to my mind is [Ali Sayed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ali_H._Sayed).

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo the ODE would consist of a linear combination of functions which are monomials and trigonometric functions of $\mathbf{x}$. The coefficients, $\boldsymbol{\beta}$, of that linear combination have a covariance matrix as they are estimated using a least squares regression.

Is my idea correct in principal, if maybe limited to certain, simple basisfunctions within the ODE, or am I completely off?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do.  Please consider providing a (very) low-dimensional example. Ideally, something physical.